# run ibm data stage job with different file in same job

Tags: excel, datastage, ibm-infosphere

I created a job to input excel data into database. I need the job to be reusable for different excel version. The columns of the excel will be the same but only the values will change, it's like inserting newest excel values version to the database.

Example, the file of `sales_report_january.xlsx , sales_report_february.xlsx` both have same columns and only the row values is different. I need the job to be able to process both files without changing anything else except the file path. Because recreating different job with the same everything(except for the filepath) for the same task seems inefficient.

Is it available to do this in ibm data stage or do i need to remap everything despite it doesn't need any change? i already tried it by changing the file path manually but it raised error.

Answer (score 1):

In a word: Parameter

Construct your job using a job parameter for the pathname of the Excel workbook.

Whichever stage you are using to read the worksheet will have the workbook name set up as reference(s) to that parameter.

Tip: Use two parameters; one for the dirname part of the pathname and one for the actual name of the workbook.  This is a more flexible design in the long run.

Comment: but for each files, then i need to edit the file name to the newest name, is it anyway for renew it automatically (perhaps there's a way to (`for files in dir : param_file_name1 = files`) )

Answer (score 1):

I can think of at least four ways to do this.  Usually, if the files are all in the same directory, we use looping in the sequence job to process a list of the file names obtained through an appropriate command (such as **ls -m *pattern*** for UNIX/Linux). Capture the output, convert the newlines to a delimiter such as comma if necessary, and use that list in the StartLoop activity.